# Echo value from textarea

Tags: php

This is my code for texarea that i have.

```
<textarea class="text" id="post_content_auto" name="post_content_auto"><?php echo (!empty($car_info['post_content_auto']) ? $car_info['post_content_auto'] : ''); ?></textarea>
```

I want to echo that on some other page and for that i use this code :

```
<?php  echo strip_tags($car_info['post_content_auto']); ?>
```

But it won't echo text. I tried to change `id` and `name` but still no result.

Comment: Are you using form and posting data?

Comment: use print_r($car_info);

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap that form element in a form, give it the `post` method, and an `action` that points to your PHP file. In your PHP file, access that variable as `$_POST['post_content_auto']`